# Obtener Fecha y hora actual independientemente de las del PC

Tags: visual-studio, date

Necesito saber cómo obtener la hora actual independientemente de que el usuario la cambie en el ordenador. He probado utilizar DateTime.Now.ToString() pero si cambio la fecha y hora del PC, me devuelve dicha fecha y hora errónea.
¿Hay alguna forma de obtener esto en código de **visual studio**? Creo que hay que obtenerlas de un servidor pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
Gracias

Comment: DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: ¿Qué es **código de Visual Studio**? ¿Alguna especie de *script* o plug-in especial para Visual Studio?

Comment: Por otro lado, si yo establezco la fecha del PC en el año 2000, quieres que tu programa te dé la fecha actual? Es decir, que sin importar la fecha del PC, siempre te devuelva la fecha actual? @Yussef, no creo que `UtcNow` ni ningún otro método parecido devuelva la fecha actual si la fecha del sistema está establecida manualmente en otra era. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Toda la razón, entendí otra cosa de la pregunta. Podría consultar una API que le dé hora, de esa manera creo que puede resolverlo

Comment: @MauricioContreras decía en "código de visual studio" porque estoy programando en visual studio. Me parecía que sería muy fácil obtener la fecha y hora reales (aunque el usuario cambie las del PC) pero me está resultando difícil dar con lo que me hace falta....

Comment: [**Visual Studio**](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/) es un IDE, como muchos otros. Lo usas para progamar en algún lenguaje, puede ser C, C++, C#, VB.Net, Javascript, F#, etc. Entiendes porqué pregunto ¿qué es código de Visual Studio? Porque como tal Visual Studio no es un [Lenguaje de Programación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_de_programaci%C3%B3n), por lo tanto no sería correcto decir: *código de Visual Studio*.